# Use Swift vapor inside a macOS app

Tags: swift, macos, vapor

I am not quite sure if this work - so that why I am asking this question:

I have a macOS app based on Swift that is used as a specialized CRM application. 
My client wants to use the app on different machines but the data should be fetched from one Mac. 
My consideration was to use one app as "server" and the other apps as clients connecting to this server.

- Can I use vapor inside an app for macOS for such a scenario?
- Can it be used as a library?
- I have seen that vapor comes with its own stack of environment - is it compatible to be used inside a macOS app?

Cheers

Sas

Comment: Write your server using Vapor. It cannot be included inside a macOS app. Keep in mind that the server has always to be reachable by the others. Or you can just run the server on a free dyno in Heroku

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Vapor runs correctly on macOS. There is nothing to stop you 'embedding' Vapor inside another Mac app.

Possible points of concern:

- you will need to use the Swift package manager to install Vapor and its packages.
- there are other, existing, light weight HTTP servers such as [Swifter](https://github.com/httpswift/swifter) that may better fit your needs.

But yes, you can use Vapor if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I will check out swifter! :-)

Comment: You should also check out https://github.com/vapor/engine which is Vapor's HTTP and server package. Once Xcode works with SPM this will be easier.

Comment: How would this be structured?